# PHP sprintf format

Tags: php, format, printf

If I have numbers `-4; -3.5; 0; 14.46`

What sprintf format should I use? Now I'm using `%g` but this prints for me `14` not `14,46` why? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

```
%f - the argument is treated as a float, and presented as a floating-point number
```

However, `%g` output is as following:

```
echo sprintf('%s rating is %g', 'NAME', -4)."\r\n";
echo sprintf('%s rating is %g', 'NAME', -3.5)."\r\n";
echo sprintf('%s rating is %g', 'NAME', 0)."\r\n";
echo sprintf('%s rating is %g', 'NAME', str_replace(',', '.', '1,74'))."\r\n";

/* 
NAME rating is -4
NAME rating is -3.5
NAME rating is 0
NAME rating is 14.46
 */
```

I think the problem is that `$member->rating` is float with decimal-point character `comma`.

Applying `str_replace(',', '.', $member->rating)` should solve the issue.

Try:

```
echo sprintf('%s rating is %g', 'NAME', str_replace(',', '.', $member->rating))."\r\n";
```

Comment: %f gives me `14,000000`

Comment: `echo sprintf('%s rating is %f', $member->name, $member->rating);`

Comment: It seems that problem is that `$member->rating = 14.0` not 14.46 , check the %g output above.

Comment: with `%s` everything is ok, is it bad solution?

Comment: would you run `var_dump($member->rating);` & share the output as it is ?

Comment: var_dump output: `float(1,74)`